# why is the output different when there is no "int" type declaration?

Tags: c++, variables, scope

Below are the two C++ codes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int a = 1;

int main()
{
    int a = 2;

    if(1)
    {
            a = 3;
            cout << a << endl;
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

The output is:
3
3

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int a = 1;

int main()
{
    int a = 2;

    if(1)
    {
            int a = 3;
            cout << a << endl;
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

The output is: 3 2

The two codes are similar except that the second one has "int" preceding "a=3". So, why does the "int" have such an effect on the output? I am a newbie, many thanks.

Comment: Because scoping rules? `int a = 3;` declares a new variable, `a = 3;` refers to the previously declared one

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `a = 3;` sets the existing variable `a` to the value 3. `int a = 3;` creates a new, third variable, also named `a` and initializes *that* to 3. The original variable `a` is unchanged.

Comment: Thank you! Still I am a little confused.